# Stereotype for @Inject possible?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, weld, codi

I have a recurring annotation in my app that's injecting an object created by a CDI-producer.

```
@Inject
@FlatGeometryLive
FlatGeometry geoObject;
```

I wonder if it's possible to write a stereotype "@FlatGeometryLiveInject" so that i only have to write

```
@FlatGeometryLiveInject
FlatGeometry geoObject;
```

and the object is injected. 
Is this possible with CDI 1.1 or any DI framework?

Comment: Look ahead about androidannotations http://androidannotations.org/

Comment: Sorry for confusing: App means a Web-Application in this case ;). Java EE 7 and Glassfish 4.0, not Android.

Comment: Oh sorry, i dont know why i though you are looking for android cdi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, because the frameworks you are using are aware, in specific point of their code, of annotations which name is `Inject` and `FlatGeometryLive`. If you define a new annotation how those frameworks could be aware, and act consequently, of your new created annotation?

In order to **improve your writing productivity** it's better you use your favorite **IDE's hints or templates**: you might create a shortcut for the text `aif` (Annotate with Inject and FlatGeometryLive) that your IDE will expand.